# WixEdit - create folder in specific location

Tags: wix, directory, wix3.5

I want to create folder in specific location that is different from TARGETDIR.
I'm installing to TARGETDIR located at C:\Program Files\Company\Product.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder" Name="PFiles">
            <Directory Id="COMPANYDIR" Name="Company">
                <Directory Id="PRODUCTDIR" Name="Product">
                    <Component Id="libraries" Guid="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX" Win64="yes">
                        <File Id="library.dll" Name="library.dll" Source="library.dll" />
                    </Component>
                    <Directory Id="example" Name="example">
                        <Component Id="example" Guid="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX" Win64="yes">
                            <File Id="EXAMPLE.EXE" Name="example.exe" Source="example.exe" />
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

Using this code will create folder C:\Program Files\Company\Product\example.

My goal is to create folders for example at D:\Product\logs. How can I achieve that using WixEdit?